# Adding sum of related records to model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model called `assembly` which has a manytomany relationship with `component`, in the pivot I have a field 'quantity'. In 'component' I have a field 'price'.

I'd like to be able to access the **total value of an assembly**, which is the combined:

```
component->pivot->quantity*component->price
```

For each assembly.

Questions:

- Is it good practice to add this field to the parent `assembly` model, say as 'total_price' as I need it often or should I calculate it in the controller?
- If adding it to the model is a good idea how would I do it?

Comment: Is it subject to change in time? I think you should put it in the pivot table as well as the quantity, since it depends on the latter.

Comment: I'd rather not as the underlying Component price gets edited often. nope not dependant on time.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm thinking is that the price for particular assembly could be rather static (like the price in a cart, despite the product's price changes of course). If that's not the case here, let me know and I'll help you on that